# are there closed form solution to $n \cdot y + \log(y) = x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find a closed-form solution to

> $n \cdot y + \log(y) = x$

How do we deal with the fact that there aren't, if there aren't?

Is it possible to rewrite this in a better way as a function of $x$?

Comment: Lambert W-function is closed form?

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Sorry, wrong equation

Comment: Why you don't use [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+n*y+%2B+ln%28y%29+%3D+x+for+y)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
n y + \log y = x
&\implies e^{n y + \log y} = e^x \\
&\implies y e^{ny} = e^x \\
&\implies n y e^{ny} = n e^x
\end{align*}
Now, the inverse of the function $xe^x$ is the [Lambert W-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).
So applying $W$, we get
$$
ny = W(n e^x) \implies \boxed{y = \tfrac{1}{n} W(n e^x).}
$$

(Does the Lambert W function count as a closed form?
Well, other standard functions you are used to--such as $\log, \exp,$ and $\sin$--might not have seemed like closed forms when people first used them. But what "closed form" really means is that we express the result in terms of previously-defined functions, and the Lambert W function was defined exactly for this purpose.)